# RxJs how to take multiple click last event?

Tags: rxjs

How can I take the last click event with RxJS to prevent multiple API calls of each button click?
I have a mechanism where exists the next button which increments a clientSlot #.
If the user clicked on the next button with normal speed get the next client slot data one after another. But if the user clicked fast one after another multiple times I would not want to display only the at last because it wasted time calling the APIs. because the user is unable to follow the data changes on the screen, I would like to show the latest click triggered data based on the last incremented clientSlot #.

With debouncTime usage I able to implement it, but without debounceTime usage is it possible to implement?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) for it - it will cancel unnecessary API requests

Example:

```
const yourHttpRequest$ = new Subject<InputApiData>();
const yourHttpResponse$: Observable<ClientData> = yourHttpRequest$.pipe(switchMap(
  inputApiData => this.httpService.getClientData(inputApiData)));
yourHttpResponse$.subscribe(clientData => { 
  // your logic to execute after API call was done
  });
yourHttpRequest$.next(inputApiData); // calling API
```

You have two buttons, which trigger API call. You can place API call in click event handler.

Comment: Could you show me an example? what will be the inner observable and the outer?

Comment: It seems to me it works well. Thanks!